# google chat bot webhook not working in php

Tags: php, chat, webhooks, php-curl, google-chat

Google chatbot has a webhook where users can automate chat there is a small python script to make it work but I want to do the same using php. I am using curl to hit the post method

```
$apiUrl = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAbvoeZ0w/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=h2OIcCLB6_f_XxhPX6lugnGizE88ZBBpJURFHtPfh_0%253D';
    $ch         = curl_init($apiUrl);
    //$kid_userid = "IXM_".session('user_data')['userID'];
    $data       = '{"text": "All Mock Test are Free "}';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
```

after hitting this code I am getting errors.

{
error: {
code: 400,
message: "Invalid request token h2OIcCLB6_f_XxhPX6lugnGizE88ZBBpJURFHtPfh_0%3D",
status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}

but same code when I am running on python it is working perfectly. Any Help will be very helpful. Thanks for the help in advance and I tried my best to explain .Sorry If I have made any mistake.

Comment: Hi there @Deepeshsingh! That error signals that the token isn't valid, how did you get it? It is not clear for me what method you are using in your approach, could you please clarificate that?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. I have it from another SO answer, maybe the issue is the missing `CURLOPT_POST`...

```
$uri = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAgcWhzwk/messages?key=MY_KEYI&token=MY_TOKEN";
$msg = '*Testing Curl PHP message to Google Chat*\n\n Description';
$params = '{"text": "'.$msg.'"}';
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code which I have shared is correct actually I just added the new bot URI and it worked.  THanks, everyone for your help.